# OpenLayers Popup not function

Tags: popup, openlayers, popupwindow

I write code for maps portal of the city. I have problem with my code. I thing that problem is in my js file. I didn´t find answer here and in youtube, but code still not function. When I click on polygon in map, don´t show popup window with data from geoserver. Can you help me please?

Code:

```
**Html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resource/ol/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>


    
    <title>Popup test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
      <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
      <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>

    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="/resource/ol/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

**CSS**
#map {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}


.ol-popup {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: -50px;
    min-width: 280px;
}
.ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.ol-popup:after {
    border-top-color: white;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.ol-popup:before {
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-width: 11px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
.ol-popup-closer {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 8px;
}
.ol-popup-closer:after {
    content: "✖";
}

**JS**
var mapView = new ol.View ({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat ([18.4301100, 49.8452658]),
    zoom: 12,
    
});

var map = new ol.Map ({
  target: 'map',
  view: mapView,
  controls:[],

});


var osmTile = new ol.layer.Tile ({
  title: 'Open Street Map',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
});

map.addLayer(osmTile);


var buildings = new ol.layer.Tile ({
  title: '"Budovy města',
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url:'http://192.168.1.214:8080/geoserver/GIS/wms',
    params:{'LAYERS':'GIS:budovy_meu', 'TILED':true},
    serverType:'geoserver',
    visible: true,
  
  })
});

map.addLayer(buildings);

// popup

var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

var popup = new ol.Overlay ({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250,
  },
});

map.addOverlay(popup);

closer.onclick = function(){
  popup.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

map.on("singleclick", function(evt){
  content.innerHTML = '';
  var resolution = mapView.getResolution();
 
  var url = buildings.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl (evt.coordinate, resolution, 'EPSG:5514', {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'adresa,odbor',
  });

  if (url){ 
      $.getJSON(url, function (data){
          var feature = data.features[0];
          var props = feature.properties;
          content.innerHTML = "<h3>Adresa : </h3> <p>" + props.adresa.toUpperCase() + "<p/> <br> <h3> Odbor : </h3> <p>"
          + props.odbor.toUpperCase() + "</p>";
          popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
      })
      
  } else {
      popup.setPosition(undefined);
  }
});
```

I tried:

- write code according GIS Simlified from youtube
- use code from opelayers.org
- check data on geoserver
- find answer here on stackoverflow
- turned on popup window in browser

Comment: 'EPSG:5514' is wrong.  Your view and the source both use EPSG:3857

Comment: When I change EPSG, problem is same. My layer from geoserver is in EPSG:5514. Center map is maybe in projection WGS84. It is problem?

Comment: If you have not specified a projection in ol.View or ol.source.TileWMS it will be requesting EPSG:3857 if the WMS is displaying correcting.  You will need CORS access to fetch the info request.  Try adding `crossOrigin: ''` to the ol.source.TileWMS options.  If it breaks that would explain why the info request does not work.

Comment: Yes, when I add crossOrigin:' ' to new ol.layer.Tile, map is breaking.

Comment: It can be enabled in GeoServer https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors